# Jenkins: Run Two Builds for Checkin, Feature Build and Proposed Merge Master Branch

Tags: git, jenkins

In Git, We have "feature branch" and "master branch".
Sometimes our builds work totally correct for "Feature Branch" , but after we merge to master it fails, (maybe due to different library or code references in master).

At my last company, anytime we updated a feature branch, it would trigger two simultaneous builds, a) one with feature branch only 2) and a shadow proposed changed branch which combines with master to simulate

How can I edit Jenkinsfile to conduct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either create two separate builds that have the same trigger (so that they start due to the same event), but have different Jenkinsfiles, therefore will behave differently. One can build the feature branch while the other builds the shadow branch. Or you could keep the single build and a single Jenkinsfile and have a parallel stage where you build both the feature and shadow branches side by side within the same pipeline.

You do it roughly like this:

```
        stage('Build branches') {
            parallel {
                stage('Feature branch') {
                    steps {
                        // Checkout feature branch & build
                    }
                }
                stage('Shadow branch') {
                    steps {
                        // Checkout branch, pull in master branch & build
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

or you can go to Jenkins Configure and Set here "Discover pull requests from origin"

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, do you have the jenkins build syntax code for each solution (particularly number 2)? was trying to code similarly,

Comment: I have edited the above answer with a sample. Also checkout this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/running-stages-in-parallel-jenkins-workflow-pipeline)

Comment: yeah, we're doing something similar, how do I create the merged shadow branch then?

Comment: You can just pull the master branch into your feature branch